# Hyperledger Fabric chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, vendor, chaincode

I'am trying to follow the tutorial [**Using the Fabric test network**](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html#) for the latest Version (v2.2.1) and everything works fine, up to the point where i try to intsall the chaincode with `./network.sh deployCC`.

I get the following output:

```
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'
executing with the following
- CHANNEL_NAME: mychannel
- CC_NAME: basic
- CC_SRC_PATH: NA
- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: go
- CC_VERSION: 1.0
- CC_SEQUENCE: 1
- CC_END_POLICY: NA
- CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
- CC_INIT_FCN: NA
- DELAY: 3
- MAX_RETRY: 5
- VERBOSE: false
Determining the path to the chaincode
asset-transfer-basic
Vendoring Go dependencies at ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go/
~/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go ~/fabric-samples/test-network
~/fabric-samples/test-network
Finished vendoring Go dependencies
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go/ --lang golang --label basic_1.0
+ res=0
Chaincode is packaged on peer0.org1
Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=1
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "go: inconsistent vendoring in /chaincode/input/src:
    github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.3.2: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go@v0.0.0-20200424173110-d7076418f212: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go@v1.1.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go@v0.0.0-20200424173316-dd554ba3746e: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.5.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt

run 'go mod vendor' to sync, or use -mod=mod or -mod=readonly to ignore the vendor directory
"
Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

If I try the suggested `go mod vendor` I get `go: no dependencies to vendor` as an answer.

---

Additional information:

VM: `Oracle VM VirtualBox`

Host: `Windows 10`

Linux Version:  `Distributor ID: Ubuntu   Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS   Release: 20.04   Codename: focal`

Go Version:
`go version go1.13.8 linux/amd64`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please check and change the go version in the following file:

**../fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go/go.mod**

Change the line setting the go version from

```
go 1.14
```

to

```
go 1.13
```

This solved the problem in my case.

Comment: I was facing same issue & This solved my error. Was pretty simple. I hope I had knew this earlier would have saved much time.

Answer (score 0):

try to add  GODEBUG: "netdns=go" in your peer configuration

Comment: Did you mean inside the core.yaml file? Or somewhere else? thx

Comment: if you are using docker-compose for peer then add as part of the environment variable. if you are running  peer as a pod in kubernetes then add it to the configmap

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

See if that helps.  It looks like the mod might be putting files in one directory and looking for them elsewhere.  By default Go now looks for Go Projects in $Home/go directory.  It might be that Go is vendoring projects in $home/go/pkg or something and that's not in your path, perhaps?

May want to look at https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html#GOPATH as well.